# Dynamic link doesn't open app on real device

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've integrated dynamic link successfully but for some reason when I build the app and install it on a real device, the dynamic link doesn't recognize that I have the app installed and opens a play store link

What I've done.

1. Added SHA-1 and SHA-256 in firebase console.
2. Created a dynamic link domain
3. Added permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Note, this dynamic link works on the emulator but not on a real device. Also there is an issue with the assetsLink.json. Sometimes it displays the data sometimes no data is showing up just an empty array

[image: Dynamic link domain]

```
  Future<void> createDynamicLink(String offerId) async {
    //TODO: Implement for IOS
    var fallbackURL =
        Uri.parse('https://fightertofighter.wixsite.com/ftf-site');

    final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
      link: Uri.parse(
          "https://fightertofighter.wixsite.com/ftf-site?offerId=$offerId"),

      uriPrefix: "https://f2f.page.link",
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: "com.ftf.ftf",
      ),
      // iosParameters: const IOSParameters(bundleId: "com.example.app.ios"),
    );

    final dynamicLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);

    if (context.mounted) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dynamicLinkSummary',
          arguments: {'link': dynamicLink.toString()});
    }
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"  android:host="f2f.page.link"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="f2f.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Does the app really need to be on the play store for this to work on a real device?